# Relative positioning of CCSprite

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

So I have a game in Windows Phone's version of cocos2dx. There is a background (CCLayerColor) and in the middle of it I place another CCLayerColor. The problem is that, when moving a layer with sprites inside that middle layer, the movement is done relative to the whole screen, not to the layer in middle.
The code for creating this CClayerColor in the middle of the screen is:

```
mWheelMachine = WheelMachineView::create(symbolMap, path);
mWheelMachine->setContentSize(CCSize(WHEEL_MACHINE_WIDTH , WHEEL_MACHINE_HEIGHT));//values equaling one third of screen size
mWheelMachine->setPosition(ItemManager::sharedItemManager()->getItemPosition(WHEEL_MACHINE_TAG
addChild(mWheelMachine, THEME_WHEEL_MACHINE_ORDER);//position in the middle of the screen
```

"WheelMachineView" is a subclass of "CCLayerColor", while create just overrides the correspondent of CCLayerColor.
Inside this class, I have another layer that moves along with its CCSprite objects drawn inside.

```
unsigned short o;

for (unsigned short i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_WHEELS; i++)
{
WheelView* wheelLayer = WheelView::create();
wheelLayer->setIsRelativeAnchorPoint(true);
wheelLayer->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
wheelLayer->setPosition(i * WHEEL_WIDTH, -100 );
wheelLayer->setContentSize(CCSize(WHEEL_WIDTH, WHEEL_HEIGHT)); //large height value, to have room for making an animation with moving symbols

addChild(wheelLayer);
mWheels.push_back(wheelLayer);

/* Get the wheel symbols */
list<Symbol*> wheelSymbols = mWheelModel->getWheelSymbols(i);

/* Index */
o = 0;
for (list<Symbol*>::reverse_iterator it = wheelSymbols.rbegin(); it != wheelSymbols.rend(); it++)
{
  CCSprite* symbol = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrameName((*it)->getName().c_str());
  symbol->setPosition(ccp(WHEEL_WIDTH / 2, SYMBOL_HEIGHT/2 + (o++ * SYMBOL_HEIGHT) - SYMBOL_HEIGHT));
  symbol->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0.5f, 0.5f));
  symbol->setScale(SYMBOL_SCALE_FACTOR);
  wheelLayer->addChild(symbol, 10, o);     
}
```

}

So, when moving 'wheelLayer' to a position outside the content size of 'mWheelMachine', it will move over the entire screen, thus drawing the symbols outside the middle designated area (mWheelMachine) for that. As it has a larger size than its parent, it draws symbols outside the parent.
Why is this happening? How can I make it to only use mWheelMachine's content size?

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine cclayer is a node, it does not have the concept of size and anchor and set its content size does not have a role on the show's content, it will only affect the control area.

I think you should just hope that some of the pictures to be displayed in a region. Using a mask will be a good solution.

Comment: So do you know how to use a mask? I mean there should be some way to bound some pictures to a specific area of the screen, such that, when moving the pictures up and down, this movement happens only inside that area